# poque aparece isso quando compila? "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: c, ponteiro, alocação

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int funcao(int **piParametro)
{
    
printf("%p\n",&piParametro);
printf("%p\n",piParametro);
printf("%p\n",*piParametro);
printf("%d\n",**piParametro);

return 0;
}

int main()
{
    
int *piVariavel;

*piVariavel = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
*piVariavel = 20;

printf("%p\n",&piVariavel);
printf("%p\n",piVariavel);
printf("%d\n",*piVariavel);

funcao( &piVariavel );

return 0;

}
```

Comment: aqui está o problema: \*piVariavel = (int\*) malloc(sizeof(int));

Comment: que deveria ser "piVariavel = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));"

Comment: vou explicar: *piVariavel, é para acessar o ponto da memoria para o qual o ponteiro aponta, como você não alocou nada, antes de acessar, esse ponteiro ta com um valor inválido, e invés de você atribuir o ponteiro de malloc a ele, você estava tentando atribuir ao ponto ao qual ele apontava